# Iterate over sheet using GS while there is any data in columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to do a small script, its basic idea is to have a sheet with names in one columns and some random info in another (to the right). The sheet has some count (unknown in advance) of such records, so they are like

```
 John   39483984
 George 3498349
 Layla  23948
```

So that a user can enter any number of such simple records, my script must create a file for each name (file is of the same name) and write the number into that file. I managed to find how to create files (though still couldn't find out how to create file in the current folder, same as where the sheet is located - this is just a side question, but if you know how to do it, please tell me). The only real problem is iterating through the records. My idea was to go through them one by one and stop when there is an empty record - basic strategy, but I wasn't able to find how to implement it (yep!). There are range functions, but there I should know in advance the range; also there is a function to get selected cells but that will require a user to select the records, which is strange.

So please suggest me a solution if it exists in this frustration Google Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createFilesForEachNameInSheet() {

  // First, you connect to the spreadsheet, and store the connection into a variable
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_KEY_GOES_HERE"); // you do know how to get the spreadsheet key, right?

  // Then, you take the sheet from that spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Then, the "problematic range". You get the ENTIRE range, from end to end, as such:
  var wholeRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());

  // Then, you fetch its values:
  var rangeValues = wholeRange.getValues();

  // At this point you have a bi-dimensional array, representing the rows and columns. 
  // Assuming you have 2 columns, in the first column you have the names, and in the second you have the unknown value
  // You need to use the already known for loop, iterate over all the data, and store it first in an object, so that you create the file only ONCE.

  var objectData = {};

  for (var i=0;i<rangeValues.length;i++) {
    var thisName = rangeValues[i][0];
    var thisValue = rangeValues[i][1];
    if (objectData.thisName == undefined) objectData.thisName = [];
    objectData.thisName.push(thisValue);
  }

  // Now we have our values grouped by name. 
  // Let's create a file for each name.

  for (var name in objectData) {
    DriveApp.createFile(name, objectData.name.join("\n"));
  }

  // NOTE: if you want to create into a specific folder, you first target it, using the DriveApp:
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("the folder name goes here");

  // folders variable is now an iterator, containing each folder with that name.
  // we will iterate over it as follows, and select the one we want. 
  // the logic for it, you'll select one of your choice:

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var thisFolder = folders.next();
    if (/* condition to check if we found the right folder */) {
      thisFolder.createFile(name, objectData.name.join("\n"))
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need to add some prose describing how to apply this code-only answer to solve the problem. There were lots of questions in that rant, are you sure you answered all of them?

Comment: I know what you mean :) but I kinda got the feeling it's enough. Hopefully we'll get some feedback from Gonzalez soon.